# Reset calculations

Tags: cognito-forms, calculator

I've set up a form to choose either hotel or camping using radio buttons. I then have a dropdown that appears asking how many rooms are required or camping pitches, depending on what radio button is selected. These are priced and calculated automatically, but I've hit a problem that I can't get my head around.

If someone selects hotel and then two rooms it adds up fine, but if they change their mind and select camping I need the two selected hotel rooms to reset to null - currently if a camping pitch is selected it adds it to the total of two hotel rooms.

Hopefully that makes sense and someone can help with the calculations necessary?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a fairly complex expression.  If possible, please submit this question via the support link (Under *My Account* in the top-level navigation) so that we can provide specific support.

<sub>Disclaimer: I am an Engineer on the Cognito Forms team</sub>